# What does K-2SO stand for?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

K-2SO is one of the many highlights of [Rogue One: A Star Wars Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/).

[image: K-2SO]

Other [droids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R2-D2#Design) from the [Star Wars universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55876/what-is-the-origin-or-significance-of-c-3pos-name) have names that have some significance. Is this the case with K-2SO?

What does K-2SO stand for?

Comment: Actually it's a joke! The pronunciation should be something like "Kay Too Asshole", and the droid personality really mean it! Am I the only one who got it???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## In-universe

According to official novelization by Alexander Freed, it was a part of his longer official designation:

> Cassian had killed K-2SO (**whose true designation was far longer and far grander, rich with meaning and history that described his factory of origin, the date and time of his initialization, and more**) and brought him back both smaller and larger than he had been. K-2SO did not mourn for his old self, but there were times he grew wistful over what he had been.
> (*Chapter 19*)

As additional confirmation, this was true of all droids in pre-Disney canon.

Quoting from [my own answer on SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110366/976):

> Pablo Hidalgo (Internet Content Provider for starwars.com) answered this conclusively in Q&A in Star Wars Insider #58 (Page 97)
>
> He said that 4-letter robot names are just fragments of long serial numbers. And some droids don't even have a shorter 4-letter name for some, who instead get a real nickname (e.g. Corran Horn's Wistler).

Please note that the canonical status of Star Wars Insider information is questionable in new Disney canon, but Pablo Hidalgo is still pre-eminent canon expert at Lucasfilm Story Group, and as such the fact that a nearly identical fact was included in a canon novel probably means that the overall general rule also remain canonical.

---

## Out of universe

We don't know specific reasons out of universe for the name (even interview with the actor [Alan Tudyk](http://www.blastr.com/2016-8-11/alan-tudyk-imperial-origins-rogue-ones-security-droid-k-2so) offers no clues).

All we know is:

> This towering, powerful security droid is described by Edwards as “**the antithesis of C-3PO**.” ([Gareth Edwards to EW](http://www.ew.com/gallery/star-wars-rogue-one-characters/2642938_k-2so-alan-tudyk))

Answer (score 2):

According to the accepted answer on SFF.SE question: [Do all droids have a four alphanumeric character name and does this have any significance?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96372/do-all-droids-have-a-four-alphanumeric-character-name-and-does-this-have-any-sig)

> 4-letter robot names are just fragments of long serial numbers.

So, there is no *in-universe* significance to the name K-2SO, it is just a fragment of his serial number.

(Out-of-universe, there *may* be some significance, but I suspect the writers just thought it sounded good).

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research online, and finding very little. My guess is K-2SO may be a chemistry joke.

> K = Potassium
>
> S = Sulphur
>
> O = Oxygen

K<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>3</sub> is [Potassium Sulfite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_sulfite), a food preservative.

> K-2SO fulfills the role of preserving Cassian and Jyn, saving them from "spoilage"

As Adeptus said, all droids have a 4 character alphanumeric name, shortening K<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>3</sub> to K-2SO.

It gets more interesting:

the people he preserves have food related names:

- Jyn (gin) &
- Cassian (Cassia) - Cassia is a common cinnamon alternative

Comment: I'd love this to be true :D

Comment: @BigTallJosh - sorry, it isn't

Answer (score 0):

I know the canonical explanation to droid names is that they are shortened from longer alphanumeric serial numbers, and usually the first letter(s) designate the droid series they belong to (KX-series in this case). Still, people who write the characters have to think about how the "name" sounds and what associations it brings to mind, and how they fit the character.

I've always been of a mind that K-2SO sounds like a chemical compound, but it isn't a complete formula. However, it invokes the thought of potassium and sulfur salts. Potassium sulfide is just KSO, so the "2" seems to point more to sulfate or sulfite. I'm not familiar with the food preservative K2SO3, but K2SO4 (potassium sulfate) is found in plant fertilizers. It is corrosive and irritant, so it would fit the droid's character nicely. You could also argue, that as a fertilizer, it's "full of shit", which also would fit the previously mentioned pronunciation joke "Kaytoo-Asshole".

Tenuous, I know, but just some thoughts that came to mind.

Answer (score -4):

I like the chemical analogy.  Here's a physics + Hewbrew gematria one that ties K-2SO with C-3PO.  Assume K is temperature in degrees Kelvin, and C is temperature in degrees Celsius (°K = °C + 273).  In Hebrew gematria S=90, P=60, and O=50.  Assume these are factors to be multiplied:

K-2SO = 2 × 90 × 50 = 9,000°K

C-3PO = 3 × 60 × 50 = 9,000°C

The same product indicates K-2SO is a character equivalent replacement of C-3PO. 
And both temperatures correspond to A type stars (which include Vega and Sirius A). 
 These may be just random letters and numbers, but that won't stop us from trying to assign meaning to them!*

*But lots of down votes when someone tries to might.  The answer "Nothing" to the OP's question may be correct, but quoting K-2SO, "I thought it was boring."

Comment: It is rather a tenuous link given that you have to invoke both Hebrew gematria and physics that produces *different* temperatures, thus invalidating your "they are symbolically identical" argument. (9000C = 9273K)

Comment: Yes very tenuous.  To stretch it further, the movie "K-9000" was about a crime-fighting dog with a cybernetic mind.   I wonder if it.. nah!